# saving an auto incremented ID into another table after a new user is registrated (PHP, mysqli)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to save the auto incremented ID that'll be created in the table 'accounts' when a new user filled out the registration form in the second table 'userdaten'.

[image: image of table 'accounts']

[image: image of table 'userdata']

The code saves the data in both tables like it should, but I still need to get the auto incremented 'id' from table 'accounts' into my table 'userdaten'

```
if ($stmt = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO accounts (username, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)')) {

    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $_POST['username'], $password, $_POST['email']);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo 'Data saved in table accounts';

    $stmt2 = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO userdaten (name, vorname, gebdatum, strasse, hnr, plz, ort) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt2->bind_param('sssssss', $_POST['name'], $_POST['vorname'], $_POST['gebdatum'], $_POST['strasse'], $_POST['hausnummer'], $_POST['plz'], $_POST['ort']);
    $stmt2->execute();
    echo 'Data saved in table userdaten';
```

I tried to make it work with `mysqli_insert_id` for the past hour, but I couldn't make it work.

Any idea what I have to change? the code above gives no error and is functional, with the exception that the auto incremented 'id' is only saved in 'accounts'.

Comment: So you want the record in `userdata` to have the same `id` as the one that auto-generated with you insert in `accounts`?

Comment: yes! the ID in `accounts` gets automatically created after a new user filled out the registration form. now I want the same ID from `accounts` to be saved in the `userdata` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) to get the auto-increment `id` value from the last insert query and use it in your current one. So change your `userdaten` query to:

```
$stmt2 = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO userdaten (id, name, vorname, gebdatum, strasse, hnr, plz, ort)
                        VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
```

Comment: hey, thank you very much! I thought I tried that earlier, but apparently I f*cked up somewhere, lol. it works now :) appreciate the help, cheers my friend